# How do I keep state when updating ReCaptcha value for form validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, recaptcha, yup

My goal is to incorporate ReCaptcha as a step in my validation. Before attempting to implement ReCaptcha the validation with Yup worked as intended.

The problem with my implementation of ReCaptcha is that whenever the user submits the ReCaptcha response, it clears out the form values.

[Example of Form Being Cleared on ReCaptcha Submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jqdG.gif)
(The console log "false" updates formValues.captcha on every change)

My intention was to use the setFormValues function to change the formValues.captcha state from false to true, like so.

```
setFormValues({...formValues, captcha:true})
```

Here is the code below. I am happy to supplement any additional information I can to resolve this issue.

Contact Form:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-recaptcha";

import Footer from '../footer'
import { useMediaQuery } from '../hooks/mediaQuery'
import Teamwork from '../../static/images/teamwork.jfif'
import contactUsSchema from '../validation/contactUsSchema'
import { Agent } from '../teamBio/agentInfo/agentInfoList'

import './style.css'

const testAPI = 'http://localhost:5000/api/send'

const initialValues = {
    intent: {
        buy: true,
        sell: false,
        lease: false,
        offerToLease: false,
        consult: false,
    },
    timeframe: {
        lessThan3: true,
        lessThan6: false,
        lessThan12: false,
        nextYear: false,
    },
    agent: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    message: '',
    captcha: false,
}

const initialFormErrors = {
    intent: '',
    timeframe: '',
    agent: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    message: '',
    captcha: '',
}


export default function Contact() {
    // const [captchaValue, setCaptchaValue] = useState(false)
    const isHidden = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 1023px)');
    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues)
    const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState(initialFormErrors);
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

    // const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);

    //////////////// HELPERS ////////////////
    const postNewMessage = message => {
        axios.post(testAPI, message)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.status === 'success') {
                    alert('Message Sent.');
                }
                else if (res.data.status === 'fail') {
                    alert('Message failed to send.')
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setFormValues(initialValues)
            })
    }

    var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        console.log(formValues.captcha)
        console.log('response',response)
        setFormValues({...formValues, captcha:true})
    };

    //////////////// EVENT HANDLERS ////////////////
    
    const onInputChange = evt => {
        const { name, value } = evt.target
        Yup
            .reach(contactUsSchema, name)
            .validate(value)
            .then(valid => {
                setFormErrors({
                    ...formErrors,
                    [name]: ""
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setFormErrors({
                    ...formErrors,
                    [name]: err.errors[0]
                })
            })
        setFormValues({
            ...formValues,
            [name]: value
        })
        console.log(formValues.captcha)
    }

    const onSubmitHandler = evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        const newMessage = {
            intent: formValues.intent,
            timeframe: formValues.timeframe,
            name: formValues.name.trim(),
            email: formValues.email.trim(),
            phone: formValues.phone.trim(),
            message: formValues.message.trim(),
            agent: formValues.agent
        };
        if(formValues.captcha === true){
            console.log('here is the message... ', newMessage)
            postNewMessage(newMessage);
        }
        else {alert('please complete the captcha')}
    }


    //////////////// SIDE EFFECTS //////////////// 
    useEffect(() => {
        contactUsSchema.isValid(formValues).then(valid => {
            setDisabled(!valid);
        })
    }, [formValues])

    return (
        
        <div className="wrapper">
            
            <div className="flexColumn">
                <div className="content-row">
                    <form className="contact-us" onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
                        <label>I am looking to:</label>
                        <select
                            value={formValues.intent}
                            onChange={onInputChange}
                            name="intent"
                        >
                            <option value=''>Please select an option</option>
                            <option value="buy">Buy</option>
                            <option value="sell">Sell</option>
                            <option value="lease">Lease</option>
                            <option value="offerToLease">Offer to Lease</option>
                            <option value="consult">Consult/Other</option>
                        </select>

                        <label >My Timeframe is:</label>
                        <select
                            value={formValues.timeframe}
                            onChange={onInputChange}
                            name="timeframe"
                        >
                            <option value=''>Please select an option</option>
                            <option value="lessThan3">Less than 3 months</option>
                            <option value="lessThan6">Less than 6 months</option>
                            <option value="lessThan12">Less than 12 months</option>
                            <option value="nextYear">Next year</option>
                        </select>

                        <label> Agent:</label>
                        <select
                            value={formValues.agent}
                            onChange={onInputChange}
                            name='agent'
                        >
                            {/* <option value={Agent.JasonTest.email}>Jason Test</option> */}
                            <option value={Agent.MarkHughes.email}>Please select an agent</option>
                            <option value={Agent.AndreFournier.email}>Andre Forunier</option>
                            <option value={Agent.Libby.email}>Libby Brignon (Land)</option>
                            <option value={Agent.MarkHughes.email}>Mark Hughes (Team Lead | Generalist)</option>
                            <option value={Agent.SueNa.email}>Sue Na (Flex/Industrial | Multi Unit | Retail)</option>
                            <option value={Agent.TommyShort.email}>Tommy Short</option>
                            <option value={Agent.VanSpears.email}>Van Spears (Multi-Family | Industrial | Leasing | Investment)</option>
                            <option value={Agent.WillSchnieder.email}>Will Schnieder</option>

                        </select>


                        <label>Full Name</label>
                        <input
                            value={formValues.name}
                            onChange={onInputChange}
                            type='text'
                            placeholder='full name'
                            name='name'
                        />

                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <input
                            value={formValues.email}
                            onChange={onInputChange}
                            type='email'
                            placeholder='email address'
                            name='email'
                        />

                        <label>Phone Number</label>
                        <input
                            value={formValues.phone}
                            onChange={onInputChange}
                            type='tel'
                            placeholder='phone'
                            name='phone'
                            maxLength='10'
                        />

                        <label> Message</label>
                        <textarea
                            value={formValues.message}
                            onChange={onInputChange}
                            type='text'
                            className="message-box"
                            placeholder='type your message here'
                            name="message"
                        />
                        <ReCAPTCHA
                            sitekey="~ ~ ~ R E D A C T E D ~ ~ ~"
                            verifyCallback = {verifyCallback}
                        />
                        <button disabled={disabled} onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>Send</button>

                    </form>
                    <img style={styles.container(isHidden)} id="teamworkimg" alt="generic team working together" src={Teamwork} />
                </div>
            </div>


            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

const styles = {
    container: isHidden => ({
        display: isHidden ? 'flex' : 'none',
    })
};
```

Validation Schema:

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Agent } from '../teamBio/agentInfo/agentInfoList'

const phoneRegExp = /^((\\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \\-]*)|(\\([0-9]{2,3}\\)[ \\-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \\-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \\-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/

const contactUsSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup
        .string()
        .min(3, "Name must be at least 3 characters long.")
        .required("Name is required"),
    email: Yup
        .string()
        .email("Must be a valid email address.")
        .required("Must include email address."),
    phone: Yup
        .string()
        .matches(phoneRegExp, 'Phone number is not valid')
        .max(10, 'Please double check your phone number')
        .min(10, "Phone number must include area code.")
        .required("Phone number is required"),
    intent: Yup
        .string()
        .oneOf(['buy','sell','lease','offerToLease','consult'])
        .required("intent is required"),
    timeframe: Yup
        .string()
        .oneOf(['lessThan3','lessThan6','lessThan12','nextYear'])
        .required("timeframe is required"),
    agent: Yup
        .string()
        .oneOf([Agent.AndreFournier.email, Agent.MarkHughes.email, Agent.Libby.email, Agent.SueNa.email, Agent.JasonTest.email, Agent.TommyShort.email, Agent.VanSpears.email, Agent.WillSchnieder.email, Agent.Antonia.email,'NA']),
    message: Yup
        .string(),
    captcha: Yup
        .boolean()
        .oneOf([true])
        .required()

})

export default contactUsSchema
```

This is my first stackoverflow post, please be kind, and thank you all for your insight.

Comment: I'm not clear if you are trying to process the ReCaptcha validation from the client / browser or on your web server. When the page's inputs are submitted, if your server processed both the ReCaptcha validation and the input validation together; that should resolve your state issue. Can you elaborate on what does the ReCaptcha validation and what happens after it is successfully validated?

Comment: Hi John, thank you for taking the time to reply. I'm not sure if I am answering this question correctly, but here goes. I'm not even dealing with validating the captcha response yet. I am just trying (at a minimum) to update the formValues to show formValues.captcha = true, whenever there is ANY response from the ReCaptcha callback which happens in verifyCallback().

Currently nothing in my JS validates the captcha response. The verifyCallback() function just fires setFormValues() when the captcha is submited/completed.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript from the client to submit the ReCaptcha request and then process the response on the client?

Comment: That’s exactly correct. Client JS handles the reCaptcha update in verifyCallback().

Comment: What does the "reCaptcha update" do?  The reCaptcha response should be a binary result: the inputs are from a human - yes or no. The inputs from your web page should not be altered by the results of the reCaptcha response. Is your reCaptcha request made synchronously with a timeout mechanism? If this request is made asynchronously, that could cause the other UI inputs to be lost.